# Conditionally update selection list when value in input field changes in a row of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to update selection list based on value in input field. Because of the update delay I do not want to update the selection list if it already has correct options. Shouldn't be too difficult I thought and tried this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.inputValue}"> 
      <p:ajax update="#{bean.updateElement}">               
</p:inputText> /
<h:selectOneMenu id="so" value="#{bean.soValue}">
      <f:selectItem />
      <f:selectItems value="#{bean.options}" var="option" itemLabel="#{option}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But it does not work because `bean.updateElement` does not get called when value in input field changes.

OK I need to use `p:remoteCommand` then. I was sure it would work with this:

```
<p:ajax oncomplete="updateSelect()"/>
```

..

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateSelect" update="dt:so" oncomplete="alert('done')" />
```

The fields are in a `p:dataTable id="dt"` row. I get the alert but `bean.options` is still not called. If I change it to `update="dt"` it works and the whole datatable is updated but that's not what I want. I also tried with `so` `form:dt:so` and `:form:dt:so`.

Then I tried a couple of more options I could find:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("dt:so");
```

..

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("dt:so");
```

but nothing happens. Tried also without `dt:`.

**Edit:**

I got one step closer this way:

```
<p:ajax update="@this #{bean.updateElement}"/>
```

Now `bean.updateElement` gets called every time I change input field value but the select component does not update until the *next time* I change the input field value. `bean.updateElement` returns "so" or "" depending on input field value.

**Edit 2:**

Using this the selected option stays when input field is modified:

```
<f:ajax execute="so" render="so" partialSubmit="true" />
```

I also tried with `<p:ajax process="so" update="so />` but the options are not any more updated. Keeping the selected option was one of my goals so this is good but could be better still.

How can I make this very simple thing work? My setup is this:

- Tomcat 7.0.53
- Mojarra 2.2.7
- primefaces-5.0.jar
- JRE 1.8.0_05

Comment: Maybe this would finish it `<p:ajax update="@this #{bean.updateElement}" partialSubmit="true"/>`

Comment: I've tried that but it does not help.

Comment: Please post the code of the method `updateElement`.

Comment: It returns "so" or "" depending on input field value.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Ajax API` section of the [PF documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation)? You might be able to hack something together that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this ajax line:

```
<p:ajax partialSubmit="true" oncomplete="checkIt(#{iIndex})" />
```

This calls my JS function passing the row index to it. The function will check if the select list needs to be updated. If it does then I click this button from JavaScript:

```
<p:commandButton id="btnUpdateList" update="so" partialSubmit="true" style="display:none"/>
```

This way it works but list update is a bit slow, maybe because it goes to server two times.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what your method `updateElement` does, but in

```
<p:ajax update="#{bean.updateElement}">
```

the attribute `update` should contain ids of the components to be updated.
So maybe this would work for you:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.updateElement}" update="so">
```

Comment: `updateElement` returns "so" if options need to be updated and "" if not. The problem is that the method does not get called when input field value changes. In your solution the selection list is updated always when input field value changes which is not what I want.